# "no matching function call for async in clion"

Tags: c++, asynchronous, clion, cgal, clang-tidy

might be needing your wisdom here! I'm using std::async() as following:

```cpp
std::vector<std::future<void>> futures; // store the return value of std::async, necessary step to make async work
std::mutex nef_mutex; // for thread-safety

void expand_nef_async(
   Nef_polyhedron& nef,
   std::vector<Nef_polyhedron>* expanded_nefs_Ptr,
   double minkowski_param) {}

// call std::async

void expand_nefs_async(
   std::vector<Nef_polyhedron>& nefs,
   std::vector<Nef_polyhedron>& expanded_nefs,
   double minkowski_param = 0.1)
{
  for (auto& nef : nefs) {
   futures.emplace_back(
      std::async(
         std::launch::async, /* launch policy */
         expand_nef_async, /* function will be called asynchronously */
         nef, /* arguments - a nef */
         &expanded_nefs, /* arguments - pointer to expanded_nefs vector */
         minkowski_param /* arguments - minkowski_param (default is 0.1)*/
      ));
  }
```

The problem is, this code runs fine and no error hints in Visual Studio 2019, but in CLion the .clang-tidy says "no matching function call for async", but it can be compiled and it can run also in CLion, so I'm wondering the reason.

Compiler: MSVC(cl.exe)
Generator: Ninja
C++ standard: C++ 11

I tried set the C++ standard to C++ 17 but it is the same error, I also tried MinGW compiler and the error remains.

Comment: Do you include the `<future>` header?

Comment: Please try to create a [mre] to show us.

Comment: There are limitless ways to confuse IDEs. Have different compilers / standard libraries in search path, use arcane build scripts ... etc. What you have done in particular is impossible to tell.

Comment: I think you need `std::ref(nef)` since `std::async` stores a copy of the arguments you pass it and moves them into the function.

Comment: Also please remove the tag cgal, as it is not cgal specific.